# Could 3D printing be done at a distance e.g. by pointing laser?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, 3d-printing

Could 3D objects be printed from a distance? Say, by pointing a laser at a stone wall?

I'm not concerned with whether the requisite technology already exists or would be difficult to build, but rather, whether something like this could be built in principle, or if there is either a law of physics or a massive intractability that would prevent it.

If it is possible, I'm interested in the theoretical limits. How far away can the material be (e.g. can we print something on the moon with a laser stationed on earth)? Can any material be used? Etc.

Comment: Engineering.se is nonspeculative. All current 3D printing methods work by providing a material flow. So the local situation must be quite special.

Comment: In addition to material flow issues there would be the issues of beam divergence over such a distance & the precision of beam placement on the moon. A minute error in beam position angle on Earth would be a significant distance on the moon.

Comment: I think position error is the key problem here - the best mechanisms that we have for aiming lasers can provide pinpoint accuracy up close, but as you increase the distance from the source, the error would quickly become much too large for the printed object to remain useful

Comment: A laser on it's own can only *remove* material, not do additive printing.

Comment: @Transistor What if the object is in some special gaseous athmosphere what solidifies on heat? My first idea is to have a nearly-100% acetylene atmosphere, mixed with some catalyzer / stabilizer. It would be transparent, so it would not interact with the laser beam, but it would heat the target object on its entry point, resulting the condensation of some poliymer. Although I am not very sure if any practical usage of such a system would worth its price.

Comment: @peterh that would satisfy special condition yes. There have been some applications where similar things have been done.

Comment: @Transistor ablation is commonly done with a laser true. But the laser is capable of doing additive manufacturing too, if there is a material flow present then it can eventually accumulate a structure, as the laser can sinter or supply energy for chemical reactions. But as a manufacturing method its just as valid to remove material.

Comment: @joojaa: I'm aware of that and have used the technique in a FormLab (liquid / laser cured) 3D printer. It's not in the question though.

Comment: Does the following read like what you are envisioning?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_laser_melting

Comment: I don't think so: "With selective laser melting, thin layers of atomized fine metal powder are evenly distributed using a coating mechanism onto a substrate plate, usually metal, that is fastened to an indexing table that moves in the vertical (Z) axis. This takes place inside a chamber [...]" Sounds like it requires placing machinery at the destination. In that case, one might as well place the whole printer at the destination, and not print at a distance. Part of the challenge is not placing any material at the destination and only using the raw material that's already present.